# Symfony FS/SolrBundle search within multiple entities

Tags: symfony, search, solr, bundle, entities

Is it possible to set up a search for multiple entities, using the Florian Semm Solr Bundle in Symfony? I'm completely lost, have looked in the documentation of Solarium itself, but couldn't figure out how to set up a search for our Symfony project.

Here's what I did so far:

- Solarium and the SolrBundle are both successfully installed.
- I indexed 3 entities (for now) with the Solr annotations like that:

  ```
  /**
   * @Solr\Document(repository="UserBundle\Entity\User")
   * @Solr\Document(index="*")
   */
  class User {
     /**
      * @Solr\Id
      */
     protected $id;

     /**
      * @Solr\Field(type="string")
      */
     protected $firstName;

     /**
      * @Solr\Field(type="string")
      */
     protected $lastName;
   }
  ```
- I set up a controller where I call the solr.client but that's basically how far I got. I can show you my code but it's throwing error messages, because I'm basically just trying around:

  ```
  class SearchController extends Controller {   
      /**   
       * @Route("/search-result/",  name="searchBundle")   
       */ 
      public function searchAction(Request $request) {   
          $client = $this->get('solr.client');   
          $query = $client->createSelect();    
          $query->setQuery($request->query->all());

          // this executes the query and returns the result 
          $resultset = $client->execute($query);

          return $this->render('SearchBundle::search.html.twig', array(
              'resultset' => $resultset
          )); 
      } 
  }
  ```
- How do I get the controller/the bundle to search within all the three bundles/indexed properties?
- How do I structure the output?

Couldn't find any tutorials/example codes/guidelines for that specific bundle unfortunately.

Comment: so what you trying to do? building an api? Do you want to handle the output just in twig or do you want to build a api request with javascript? JSON format for api's are common. In twig you can easily handle objects. Do you use repositories? The Controller should just handle the data not fetching it from database.

Comment: Puh I try to give my best answering your questions:
I was thinking about setting up a SearchController, handling the search requests. So no javascript, no. And twig I'd only like to use for displaying the data/results, I got from the Controller. I already have this, it's just a simple table, going through the results, my Controller would give. And yes, each of my entities has a repository. 
Other than that hmm, I'm lost. I have no clue how the search is working etc..

Comment: @Violence any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do inside your controller is get a repository for the search;

```
$resultset = $this->get('solr.client')->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findAll();

return $this->render('SearchBundle::search.html.twig', array(
    'resultset' => $resultset
));
```

Source: https://github.com/floriansemm/SolrBundle#query-a-field-of-a-document